# Best practices for fixing a broken branch in Git?

Tags: git

Assuming that the "master" branch must always be stable what is the best practice for fixing "master" if by accident a feature is merged into "master" which breaks it and master has been pushed to the remote?

I have worked with resetting to a previous stable commit and then doing a `push --force` on "master" on that commit, but I think its' a bit nasty approach since it involves rewriting history.

Here we find a suggestion for doing one or more revert commits:
[How to do emergency fixes on master in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328400/how-to-do-emergency-fixes-on-master-in-git)

That is also a bit tedious if you for some reason have merged a feature containing 5+ commits (as I understand you can only revert one commit at a time).

Any suggestions for fixing a broken branch that I have not thought of?

Comment: Are you the only one working on that repository? Have you already made the broken `master` branch public (in other words, have you already pushed it to some remote with shared access)? Also, adding an ASCII graph representing your recent history would help you get a definite answer; in Git, the best course of action often depends on the particular situation you're facing.

Answer (score 2):

If the break is a result of a bad merge then you simply revert the merge commit itself with

```
git revert -m 1 $merge_sha
```

This is presuming ^1 was master.

This will revert all the changes introduced by the merge commit, whether it was from 1 commit or 500 commits.

In the future, in order to 'under' the revert, you will need to revert the reverted sha.

See also [Revert Faulty Merge HowTo](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

Comment: -m == mainline == history you want to keep.  For the typical case of `git checkout master` then `git merge feature` where a new merge commit was created then -m 1 should be correct I think.  There are other cases where it wouldn't be though.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `git revert` of a merge your history will look like this

```
     o--o--o
    /       \
o--o------o--o----------------o

             ^                ^
             |                |
           merge           merge reverted
```

If you do a forced push it looks like this

```
     o--o--o
    /       
o--o------o
```

If no other developer has already pulled the merge than it would be better to do a forced push, because the history will be more clear.

E.g. is the branch really merged?

```
     o--o--o
    /       \
o--o------o--o--------------------o

             ^                    ^
             |                    |
Seems to be merged here, but reverted here.
```